# Checkbox groups in asp

Tags: asp-classic

I ran into a strange problem with checkbox groups. I am trying to get the values from a group of checkboxes, but I have to hit the submit button twice for it to get the values... I have no idea why. I also use a dropdown box on the same form and I only need to hit the button once to get its value.

my asp code to write it to page

```
 Dim selectFormValue 
 selectFormValue = Replace(Request.Form("selectTest"), """", "")

 Response.write Request.Form("checkGroup")
```

here is the html being generated

```
<form method="post" name="formTest">    
    <select name="selectTest">
      <option value='123"' selected="">Option 1</option>
      <option value='124"' selected="">Option 2</option>
      <option value='125"' selected="">Option 3</option>
   </select>

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGroup" value="1" CHECKED />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGroup" value="2" CHECKED />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGroup" value="3" CHECKED />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGroup" value="4" CHECKED />       
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the complete code: including <form> ... </form>.

Comment: Are you using any javascript that might be expecting the checkboxes to be unchecked at the start ? Also what browser exhibits this behaviour ?

Comment: @Edelcom - Sorry about that. I have updated the code for you.

@Gaby - No there isn't any javascript on the page at all.

Comment: Strange - i cannot reproduce this - did you already try to emit checked="true" ?

Comment: What are you getting when you do get the values from the checkboxes? Are you getting "1,2,3,4"?

Comment: I get those values on the second click. First time around it gives nothing

Comment: @Filburt - yes, and it still does this. It seems like the form lags behind by one click. The select option box get the value right away so I am dumbfounded.

Comment: Do you guys think it has something to do with dynamically creating the checkboxes? I know in .net this can be a problem, but I wouldn't know how to solve it in asp.

Answer (score 1):

One thing i note is, that you don't specify an ***action*** in your form.

Comment: Which just means it would get posted to the same url.

Comment: @myotherme - sure, it posts to the same url but since OP states he had to submit twice it might have been worth a shot.